Computing the tangent space of the orbit of a gauge group action at a connection
Let $E\to M$ be a smooth real vector bundle, and let $\mathfrak{G}$ be the group of smooth bundle automorphisms. (The Lie algebra of $\mathfrak{G}$ is the space $\Omega^0(\text{End}(E))$.) For a conneciton $\nabla$ on $E$, an element $g\in \mathfrak{G}$ acts on $\nabla$ by $(g\cdot \nabla)_X(\sigma)=g(\nabla_X(g^{-1}\circ \sigma))$. Note that the space $\mathfrak{C}$ of all connections on $E$ is an affine space $\nabla_0+\Omega^1(M,\text{End}(E))$. In particular $(g\cdot \nabla)-\nabla \in \Omega^1(\text{End}(E))$, and it is known that $(g\cdot \nabla)-\nabla=-d^\nabla(g)g^{-1}$. Here $g$ is viewed as a section of $\text{End}(E)\to M$, i.e. $g\in \Gamma(\text{End}(E))$, and $d^\nabla$ is the covariant derivative $\Gamma(\text{End}(E))=\Omega^0(\text{End}(E))\to \Omega^1(\text{End}(E))$ induced by $\nabla$. (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)#Gauge_transformations)
I want to show that the tangent space of the orbit $\mathfrak{G}\cdot \nabla \subset \mathfrak{C}$ at $\nabla$ is precisely $\text{im}(d^\nabla:\Omega^0(\text{End}(E))\to \Omega^1(\text{End}(E)))$. The following is an argument in the book The Theory of Gauge Fields in Four Dimensions by H. B. Lawson: Given $\gamma\in \Omega^0(\text{End}(E))$, consider the curve $g_t=e^{t\gamma}$ and its corresponding curve of connections $g_t\cdot \nabla=\nabla-d^\nabla(g_t)g_t^{-1}$. Taking derivatives (fiber by fiber) gives $$ \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(g_t\cdot \nabla)=-\nabla (\gamma)=-d^\nabla(\gamma).$$
What I can't understand is: How do we take derivatives of the curve $t\mapsto \nabla-d^\nabla(g_t)g_t^{-1}$? I don't see what "fiber by fiber" means.

Intuitively, the gauge transformation $g_t$ only does anything in the direction of the fibres, and so in order to differentiate the family of curves, they can also be differentiated on each fibre separately, because there is no derivative "in the direction" of the base manifold.
